React-native-reanimated entering/exiting dosen't works on android
Description
I'm trying to use animation for entering & exiting animation and In ios its work's fine but on android its dosent works,
This is the code:
import { COLORS } from '@/src/constants/theme';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  SlideInRight,
  SlideOutLeft,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const LIST_ITEM_COLOR = '#1798DE';

interface Item {
  id: number;
}

export default function App() {
  const initialMode = useRef<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    initialMode.current = false;
  }, []);

  const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>(
    new Array(5).fill(0).map((_, index) => ({ id: index }))
  );

  const onAdd = useCallback(() => {
    setItems(currentItems => {
      const nextItemId = (currentItems[currentItems.length - 1]?.id ?? 0) + 1;
      return [...currentItems, { id: nextItemId }];
    });
  }, []);

  const onDelete = useCallback((itemId: number) => {
    setItems(currentItems => {
      return currentItems.filter(item => item.id !== itemId);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.floatingButton} onPress={onAdd}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 40 }}>+</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 50 }}
      >
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Animated.View
              key={item.id}
              entering={SlideInRight}
              exiting={SlideOutLeft}
              onTouchEnd={() => onDelete(item.id)}
              style={styles.listItem}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

The funny part is that the animation is works I try the your first animation code and width.value = withSpring(width.value + 50) Really animate the View, so the animation works but I need the entering prop to works... any ideas?
notice
on iOS works fine just android not work
Reanimated version
3.10.0 ( I try 3.6.1 too and same problem)
React Native version
0.73.6
Platforms
iOS (entering/exiting works)
Android (entering/exiting dosen't works)
Architecture
Fabric (New Architecture)
Build type
eas build dev
Device model
several android devices & android emulator
Acknowledgements
Yes
Steps to reproduce
1.Click on "onAdd" function to add more items (expecting entering with animation)
2. Get no animation at all (only with entering and exiting)

try to add some duration in entering or exiting like this:


<Animated.View
              key={item.id}
              entering={SlideInRight.duration(500).easing()}
              exiting={SlideOutLeft.duration(500).easing()}
              onTouchEnd={() => onDelete(item.id)}
              style={styles.listItem}
            />



or u can read from documentation about entering and exiting
react-native-reanimated
hopefully it can help

Yeah I tried that already... unfortunately there is still no good news...

i tried with your code is working without duration, may be you can check my snack link . (in web the animation is not working, you can try in android or ios)

Yea the old Architecture works as expected, But I need in the new Architecture (Fabric) to works at, the problem is that they say it works for the new Architecture but it dosent....

any solution to this?
